# WPF: StackOverFlowException iterating grid

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls, stack-overflow, togglebutton

This is the case:

I trying to do a extra format to my tooglesbuttons

```
private void PanelToggles_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ToggleButton currentTB = sender as ToggleButton;
    if (currentTB != null)
    {
        foreach (UIElement tb in GridToggles.Children)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(tb.GetType().ToString());
              (tb as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;
        }
        currentTB.IsChecked=true;
        currentTB.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        //implementation
    }
}
```

It throws StackOverFlowException, some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but it seems like `PanelToggles_Checked` is an event called infinite times and the reason could be because you are doing `currentTB.IsChecked = true;` in your conditional statement which triggers the event to be called again and again....